# How to create a object oriented function like in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm newbie in object oriented programming in php. I want to create a function like the database facades in laravel.

Example :

```
   $dbcon = new DBConnection();
   $dbcon->table('mytablename')->all();
```

I have function "table" in my DBConnection class but my question is how to create a function "all" that prepend in my function "table".

Can someone teach how to create something like the above function. Thanks a lot.

```
<?php

    class DBConnection {
        public $server;
        var $user;
        var $password;
        var $dbname;

        var $view;

        function __construct(){
            $this->connect();
        }

        function connect(){
            $con = mysqli_connect($this->server,$this->user,$this->password,$this->dbname);
            if($con){

                return $con;
            }
         }


    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to 'chain' methods, just return an instance via $this.
In your example:

```
public function table() {
    [...]
    return $this;
}
```

just guessing... :)
Maybe you could improve your question by providing more details.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword 'chain method'